# C - Using getchar over fgets for stdin

Tags: c, stdin, fgets, getchar

New here,

Is there any disadvantage to using `getchar()` method as opposed to `fgets()` for reading a string, other than the fact that `getchar()` reads just from `stdin` where as we can choose a stream for `fgets()`.

Assuming, I have to only work with `stdin`, is there a reason why I should or shouldn't choose one or the other?

The one advantage I see for `getchar()` is that `fgets()` requires us to specify the maximum characters that can be read in advanced, whereas we can use a buffer in case of `getchar()` to store the string and reallocate as per our need.

**[ EDIT ]**

I implemented this function to read inputs, but is there any reason to do so when `fgets()` could also suffice if the length of the string is known.

```
char *scanner ( const char *text )
{
    char *buffer = ( char * ) malloc ( sizeof ( char ) * BUFFER_SIZE );

    int token;
    int length = 0;
    int limit = BUFFER_SIZE;

    printf("%s", text);

    while ( ( token = getchar ( ) ) != '\n' && token != EOF )
    {
        buffer [ length ++ ] = token;

        if ( length > limit )
        {
            limit += 256;
            buffer = ( char * ) realloc ( buffer, sizeof ( char ) * limit );
        }
    }

    buffer [ length ] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: They are completely different things, and the best one to use depends entirely on what you're doing.

Comment: Have you considered scanf?

Comment: There is `fgetc` if you want to read a single character from a specified stream.

Comment: I understand that `getchar()` uses `fgetc()` but my question is pretty clear "Is there a reason to prefer one over the other, provided they both suffice for the task at hand. "

Comment: If inputting strings use a string based function. If inputting chars use a char based function. What Are you doing?

Comment: If your operating a menu system. I don't think that fgets will work well. I think you have to hit return to get anything. Using char based stuff for imputing strings, names, addresses etc. will require more code. For strings use the string based functions as its a lot easier.

Comment: I think fgets() will give you chunks that you can glue back together in dynamically allocated buffers if you want to do that. What are you doing?

Comment: `getchar()` vs `fgets()`?  Unless you're doing this for the purpose of learning, neither.  [If available, use `getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and get an entire line of unspecified length with one line of code: `char *line = NULL; size_t len = 0; ssize_t read = getline( &line, &len, stdin );`  There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw -- you will have to press ENTER to get character input regardless of whether `fgets()` or `getchar()` is used.

Comment: Yes, I got the fact it's about reading strings vs characters. Unless i am required to perform some character by character operations as i allocate, I shouldn't be using `getchar()` for the purpose of reading strings. The other methods should prove to be more optimal. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any disadvantage to using `getchar()` method as opposed to
>   `fgets()` for reading a string, other than the fact that `getchar()`
>   reads just from stdin where as we can choose a stream for `fgets()`.

Yes.

- `fgets()` requires only one call in the general case, and it handles recognizing end-of-line automatically.  `getchar()` needs to be called in a loop in the general case, and you need to handle line-termination recognition yourself.  That makes `getchar()` both more complicated to use and more costly for the purpose.
- Furthermore, if there is more than one place in your program where you want to read strings, you would want to put any `getchar()`-based solution into a `function` so that you can reuse it, and then you're straight to your own reimplimentation of `fgets` anyway.
- It is also reasonable to expect the experts who wrote and tuned your C library to have implemented `fgets()` more efficiently than you can reasonably expect to match by rolling your own with `getchar()`.

> The one advantage I see for `getchar()` is that `fgets()` requires us to
>   specify the maximum characters that can be read in advanced, whereas
>   we can use a buffer in case of `getchar()` to store the string and
>   reallocate as per our need.

If you mean that using `getchar()` allows you to reallocate *on a character-by-character basis* then

1. Technically, you can get that with `fgets()`, too.
2. You generally want to perform (re)allocation in larger chunks, because it is expensive.  And you can do *that* in conjunction with `fgets`, too.

Comment: The way I'm seeing it now is that I should almost always prefer `fgets()` over `getchar()` unless i want to perform operation on the characters as they are being allocated. ( Strictly speaking in terms of the example above. )

Comment: @ShauryaSingh, yes, for reading *strings*, and especially whole-line strings I agree that `fgets()` is usually to be preferred.  `getchar()` serves a different purpose.